# Is it faster to jump around?

Tags: overwatch

Is it faster to jump around to the objective rather than just plain old walking? When watching competitive gameplay of Seagull, instead of just walking normally he spends all of the time running from spawn to the objective hopping around. He will do this with almost all heroes, with Bastion, Hanzo, and Genji, his mains.

Is it faster to hop around, or to just walk?

Comment: He is probably doing it to avoid enemies from hitting him.

Comment: @ardaozkal At the setup time though? And even when they have plenty of time without seeing any enemies?

Comment: some players simply get into the flow of things early. I see this all the time.. Doesnt seem too hard to test this theory out, either.

Comment: @ardaozkal It's not when players are targeting him, it's when he's running from his spawn to the objective, not the other way around

Comment: @Timelord64 it's probably harder to test than you think; many first person shooters have bunny hopping built into the engine intentionally or otherwise, and that's a frame perfect trick.

Comment: Have you seen any other pro players doing this? If it's just one player, I'm inclined to believe the current answer is on the mark.

Comment: Very large number of pro players are doing this, not only in overwatch but in many other games. It can take a slightly different form, like clicking like crazy on a building in a RTS or just moving back-and-forth if jumping is not possible (like many MOBA's).

Comment: @Retrosaur at the setup time, if they are defending, they are going to reach earlier their defense spot under some conditions, if they are doing it in the base waiting to attack should be to tune their keyboard reflexes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it is **not** faster to jump than to walk ! However is does help to *get in the mood* !

This kind of behavior is very common for pro players and streamers during startup phase, mostly to keep the attention (of themselves and/or of watchers) on the game. It is boring to wait for the start or to walk to the first objectives, both for the player and the watchers. While this is very important for streamers, this is quite often just a sign of impatience.

In other games, this can have a slightly different form. Like clicking on buildings like crazy in RTS, moving back-and-forth on a MOBA lane, doing on-place 360° in FPS and so on...

I even saw pro players having such behaviors in Hearthstone, a card game with no movements at all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to bunny jump in most of the games is to **keep yourself in movement and  don't be an easy target** as **to use some of game mechanics in your favor**. In some games it improves your move speed but it's not the case with Overwatch (*fully*).

I gonna limit my text to Overwatch, but this is old as Doom and Quake games.

---

If you watch the latest [ESL Tournament](http://play.eslgaming.com/overwatch/) most of the players were jumping all the time, why that? 3 reasons:

1. Keep yourself in movement (Or stay away from my hitbox):

   - The hitbox in your head is gigantic, it is wider than you body, if you move in 2 axis, you let one easier to your enemies hit

     [Hitboxes in overwatch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UU8jqxAiHQ)
2. The game don't penalize you for moving:

   - If you played counter-strike you must be used to stop before shot to get better aim, or to compensate it with several techniques. You don't have it here, so you can jump and shoot all the way straight.
3. Jump *may* improve your speed, only under some conditions.

   - Not just jumping, but going diagonal of your direction. 
     In some speedrun videos people abuse the lack of normalized movement in some games. What is that?

   If you tap to walk foward, you walk 1 unity foward. If you tap to strafe, you go sideways 1 unity. But if you tap 2 butons, you walk 1*sqr(2).
   [image: 1 x square 2]

   Most of the games normalize that movement like Overwatch, but it seems that when you jump under some conditions you bypass that normalization, like with Lucio's speed boost.

   [Overwatch strafe jump to keep movement with Lucio's boost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94X9BPPH374)